# Xcode 8 and "ld: library not found for -lcrypto"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, openssl, xcode8

When I try to build my project, I get the following issue.

```
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Before the latest Xcode update, I was using OpenSSL via CocoaPods just fine. After the latest OS and Xcode update, I can't seem to be able to build OpenSSL.

Any ideas how to solve this? On Xcode 7 everything was working ok.

Comment: What is your full link command? Please add it to the question.

Comment: What is full link command? Could you please explain it

Comment: Same problem here. I created a soft-link to the openssl headers from an older SDK into the 10.12 SDK in Xcode 8. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Mark Can you give more details about where you've put the soft-link in the SDK ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution, turns out, I needed to update the CocoaPods as well as my Pods.

For Mac OS X: 
pod 'OpenSSL-OSX'

Other versions of OpenSSL do not work.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe how hard it was to find this, but this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time.
I finally fixed it by adding the following path to Build Settings: Library Search Paths

$(SRCROOT)/../../openssl-1.0.1s-MacOSX/lib

Your folder path is probably different. I pressed the plus button and dragged the lib folder from the OpenSSL folder to it.

I am sure I had tried this multiple times without success, but it seems to fix it now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error "library not found for -lcrypto" adding LIBRARY_PATH variable with the path to the library.

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

I included it on .gitlab-ci.yml, but I guess adding it elsewhere will work.